# How to create a Text Model instance manually in monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

When you create a monaco-editor instance it will come with a text model for the entire text (see `editor.getModel()`). For a mixed-language editor I want to create own models for each span of code in a specific language. What's the correct way to instantiate a text model with a given text + language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `editor` namespace contains a function specifically designed for that task:

```
const myModel = editor.createModel("let a = 1;", "typescript", myUri);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, does Monaco really give you the ability to use multiple models for the same editor? As far as I can see it only allows for one model at a time.

Comment: Not at the same time, but you can switch models. I use this to switch the content of a monaco editor instance in my preact app.

Comment: Makes sense. Although the requirement expressed as "I want to create own models for each span of code" doesn't look solvable then.

Comment: Don't forget you can use a model also outside of Monaco!. So what I have is a code block manager which holds start and end line of a piece of code in a Monaco editor and whenever I need to call an API which requires a text model (say, for code completion) I dynamically create one and use that for just this block of code.